# Flutter Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process com.viainno.homego. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

**Update 2020/12/11**
The problem solved.
The problem occurs because i edit the manifest in the plugin.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.tungwang.tappayflutterplugin">

<!--    <application-->
<!--        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"-->
<!--        tools:node="replace"-->
<!--        />-->

</manifest>
```

I comment the content then migrate it to my app's manifest.

```
<application
        android:name=".Application"
        android:label="Home Go"
        android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        tools:replace="android:label">
```

It works perfectly.

**Problem**

I got this error on android every time, and i can't receive message in my app.
I've read many answers on stackoverflow, but still facing this error.
I am really confused on this error.
Would anybody help me?
Thank a lot.

I added google-service.json in android/app
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8E3jM.png)

This is my project level build.gradle.

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        //FCM
        // Add the google services classpath
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.2'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

This is my app level build.gradle.

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.viainno.homego"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.2.4'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
}

//FCM
// ADD THIS AT THE BOTTOM
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to get an instance of Firebase without initialize it. Please add `FirebaseApp.initialize()` before you try to get an instance of Firebase.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your reply. I've try this, but i got "Firebase has not been correctly initialized. Have you added the "google-services.json" file to the project?" This is really strange.

Comment: Sure. Which part?

Comment: I found if i remove this plugin (https://pub.dev/packages/tappayflutterplugin) which i create, the error disappear. But i "have to" use this plugin in my app.

Comment: Glad you did it!